# Using C# and Blazor.... I want to be able to determine what the user selected

Tags: c#

Here is my pretty simple C# code. Writing some software for my martial arts club

Why do I get an error on this line

```
HoldTechnique = Techniques.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

it says

> Techniques does not exist in current context

This is in my Terms.razor file:

```
@page "/Terms"

<select id="Techniques" name="Techniques" runat="server" @onchange="MyVideoSrc">
    <option>Shihonage</option>
    <option>Kytenage</option>
    <option>Kotegeshi</option>
    <option>Tynohenko</option>
</select>

@code {
    private void MyVideoSrc()
    {
        string HoldTechnique = "";
        HoldTechnique = Techniques.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You need to declare Techniques as a variable in the code section, then you can bind it in the markup using the @ syntax. I'd recommend looking at some basic Blazor samples to get the core concepts down before posting questions here.

Comment: Interesting .... the reason why I thought "... it worked like that ..." is because of examples I have seen. ... Some on stack overflow. Sorry about the misprints... thanks for the edits.... I will look into some basic Blazor samples before I post here again

Answer (score 1):

I did not get much help... well ... Actually no help at all from here. I just got: **"....go look at some basic concepts before posting here...."**
I have coded for many years and I am just not familiar with How some of the stuff worked in C#/Html/Blazor.... I just wanted help with a little direction to get me pointed in the RIGHT direction. So for those who are starting out like I am .... If you are wondering it it actually pretty simple. I have done a lot of work with Forms especially .NET/VB... 
if you have a basic select statement (mine has Japanese terms)

```
<select @onchange="@DoStuff">
    <option Value="Shihonage">Shihonage </option>
    <option Value="Kytenage">Kytenage </option>
    <option Value="Kotegeshi">Kotegeshi </option>
    <option Value="Sankyo">Sankyo </option>
</select>
```

Here is your function to define your variables

```
@functions
        {
    public string selectedString = "Ikyo";

}
```

Here is your code for "DoStuff" - eventually this will be a class.. Right now it is all in the .razor file

```
void DoStuff(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + selectedString);
    }
```

Comment: You can do `public string selectedString {get;set;}="Default Value"` then `<select @bind="selectedString">...</select>` unless you need another event fired on change than just binding it.

Comment: Sometimes the right people don't get there or the post doesn't receive enough attention, don't discourage, there are people that want to help, and thanks for posting an answer to help other people out, that's what the site is for!